# OBJ Error on import

Tags: import, error, file-format

I created a 3D Title in Photoshop and exported it to an .obj file. I'm trying to import that file into Blender and I keep getting these errors.

[image]

I've tried searching the forums for a solution but can't find it.

Comment: It's either a bug in Blender's obj importer or an invalid file (read as: not following obj format specification) created by Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting your file as .stl from Photoshop. That's worked for me in the past.